# Opening a Cash Drawer using JAVA or Batch File

Tags: java, batch-file, thermal-printer

I have a Partner RP-300 receipt printer with a cash drawer connected to it for experimental purposes.It connects to the PC via LPT1.

I would like to open the cash drawer by means of a java application or a batch file.

Any ideas?

EDIT
I have found out that the command to open the drawer is ESC p, hex value \x1b\x70\x00,

but how do I send that command to the printer using cmd?, I tried putting latter in a text file, then using copy \b file name lpt1, but it just prints the contents of the text file on the printer.

Comment: For the command that does it you should read the reference manual of the printer but I know communication through parallel port can be done with the Java Comm API. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html

Comment: I read the manual and found it's command codes, but I don't know where and how to use it. I am not familiar with cmd etc. [link]http://partnertech-uk.com/files/manual/RP-300-H-manual.pdf[link] Thanks for the java link

Comment: I've looked at the command list and I can't see any commands related to the drawer functionality.

Comment: I read somewhere that the printer sends a pulse to the drawer, and there is a command for regular pulse? In anyways, how would I execute those commands?

Comment: You might have to look in to serial ports and the javax.comm package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have looked into the manual and the command includes two more parameters, pulse on and pulse off. It's also well explained here: [How to program cash drawer to open](http://www.beaglehardware.com/howtoprogramcashdrawer.html). 
So the command is `ESC p m t1 t2`, where m is relating to connector pin, and t1, t2 are high/low times. 
You send only `ESC p 0 (\x1b\x70\x00)`, while you should do eg. `ESC p 0 25 250 (\x1b\x70\x00\x19\xfa)`

copy /b is perfectly valid way of sending your control commands to the printer and it should work.

Just make sure that your file does include proper hex sequence using any hex editor.

Hope this helps

Edit: [link to technical manual](http://www.partnertechcorp.com/files/ptu/support/RP300/RP-300%20Technica%20Manual%20V11%20.pdf)

Edit: To get command sequence encoded in file (long but easy):

1. Get Notepad++

2. Check you have Converter installed under plugins. If not, find and install it 

3. Create new file in Notepad++

4. Select ANSI under encoding

5. Enter 1b700019fa

6. Select(highlight) string you entered (or select all with Ctl-A)

7. Go to plugins->Converter-> HEX --> ASCII

8. You should see garbled output (with letter p inside). Save

9. Send your file to printer.

Comment: Thank you, will test it later today. Can you suggest a good hex editor?

Comment: [You could look here:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426/what-is-a-good-windows-hex-editor-viewer) or debug for quick viewing/editing

Comment: Thanks, I tried a online converter quickly, If I input ESC p 25 250, I get this: 455343207020323520323530 , no "x"'s or "\" ? Is this correct?

Comment: Uh no... that's hex for literal `ESC p 25 250`, spaces included, and you need to have control code named ESC (1b) followed by character p (code 70) and options (full seq: 1b700019fa). `\x` (like in `\x1b`) is common notation used to write down hex numbers. You've used it so I have done also.  I will edit my answer to show how can you achieve needed result, but please read on ascii/binary. That's pretty basic...

Comment: Thanks, yes, i don't really have experience or knowledge on binary and cmd for that matter. I did try to read up, but struggle to find good articles, or even a book.

Comment: Thanks, all worked, can you just explain how you got that 25 and 250 is 19 and fa. Because I need to convert other numbers aswell.

Comment: Just to summarize all of this. After following the steps in the answer, to send the file to the printer (step 9) you can use cmd with : `copy /B "filename.txt" lpt1` (actually in my case instead of lpt1 i used com1

Comment: hey guys, i am looking to open cash drawer. but i don`t know where to start.
i am printing with the JQuery window.print();
my receipt is printing fine with 88mm thermal printer. and the Cash Drawer is already attached to the POS Printer.
i don`t know how to get it done.

Any sample code will  be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use RXTX or javax.comm(depricated) to send binary commands to an LPT port.

http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Using_RXTX

http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Parallel_Communications

Comment: Thanks, will test it later and should it work I will implement it in my final application.