# How to send ESC/POS commands to an usb printer?

Tags: java, cmd, ports, escpos

My objective is opening a cash drawer programatically,  but I didn't  found detailed information about how Java interact with Windows ports so I couldn't get it working. These are the methods I tried(no errors in Java console):

```
public void cashdrawerOpen()   {

    String code1 = "27 112 0 150 250"; //decimal
    String code2 = "1B 70 00 96 FA"; //hexadecimal
    String code = "ESCp0û."; //ascii

     PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
     System.out.println(service.getName());
     DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
    DocPrintJob pj = service.createPrintJob();
     byte[] bytes;
     bytes=code2.getBytes();
     Doc doc=new SimpleDoc(bytes,flavor,null);
      try {
        pj.print(doc, null);
    } catch (PrintException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void cashdrawerOpen2(){
    String code1 = "27 112 0 150 250";
    String code2 = "1B 70 00 96 FA";
    String code = "ESCp0û.";
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream("USB001:POS-58");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);
      ps.print(code1.getBytes());
      ps.close();
}
```

Then I started playing with cmd, specifically following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309054/opening-a-cash-drawer-using-java-or-batch-file) thread, but when I execute the command 'copy /b open.bat USB001' it just says: 'overwrite USB001 ? (yes/no/all)'

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I didn't found how to send commands over USB, I had to emulate LPT ports.

If your printer comes with a driver named TM Virtual Port Driver or something similar(in my case):

1. Install it and configure printer connection with the GUI.
2. Make use of Java methods

If not:

1. Share the printer in the control panel.
2. Open cmd as admin
3. NET USE LPT1 \[Computer-Name]\Printer
       /Persistent:Yes (doesn't work in win8.1)
4. from Java:

   ```
   public void cashdrawerOpen(){ 
       String code2 = "1B700096FA"; // my code in hex
       FileOutputStream os = null;
       try {
           os = new FileOutputStream("LPT1:POS-58");
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
         PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);
       ps.print(toAscii(code2));
         ps.close();
   }

   public StringBuilder toAscii( String hex ){
   StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
   String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
   output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
   }
    return output;

   }
   ```

Comment: `cmd` supports a limited set of "devices": `CON:` for Screen/Keyboard, `COMx:` for serial ports and `LPTx:` or `PRN:` for printer ports (see [mode command](https://ss64.com/nt/mode.html)) (basically is't historical stuff, before there was USB). So "binding" your USB to a supported "device" (as you did) is the way to go.

Comment: @Stephan I think I missunderstood. USB is before the others? Or the opposite?

Comment: ask the Microsoft programmers... I can imagine, the USB protocol is a bit more advanced than `COM` or `LPT`, which are quite simple and straightforward; I've written "drivers" for them with a few lines of BASIC back in those times. (PS: the lack of support from Microsoft is probably the reason, Virtual Port Drivers even exist)

Comment: @Stephan So, USB is newer and not fully supported. Thx for the info.

Comment: basically yes. USB is in "modern times of Windows", so they probably didn't care do adapt the "good old DOS" drivers to the new technology (as there are now Windows drivers to use)

Answer (score -1):

Well...the USB001 file must already exist in the location you're copying to and now it's asking you if you want to overwrite it since you're copying open.bat to the very same USB001 file name.

If you always want to overwrite the USB001 file then also use the /Y switch as well, for example:

```
copy /B /Y open.bat USB001
```

You can view all switches for COPY at the Command Prompt by entering:

```
copy /?
```

Comment: I thought the command was sending open.bat to the USB001 port, I have not an USB001 file, if it's not, why in the thread I linked says: 'copy /b is perfectly valid way of sending your control commands to the printer and it should work. '.

Comment: I achieve opening the cash drawer with: 'start /min notepad open.bat'. But I don't want to use notepad  because it's printing the name of the file and a lot of white space, I just need open the cash drawer. Syntax of 'start' command can be found here: [link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000932.htm) .

Comment: Update: I managed to open the cash drawer 'emulating '  LPT1 port. 1st- Share the printer in the control panel. 2nd-open cmd as admin 3rd- NET USE LPT1: \\[Computer-Name]\Printer . Then the command 'copy /b open.bat lpt1' will work. But it still printing raw data when  the cash drawer opens.

Comment: Uh? does your printer understand .bat files?? Yes, the extension doesn't matter for the machine(s) , but you really should name it `.bin` or `.dat` or `.hex` to avoid confusion